# Copy text selection to clipboard in Windows using Qt and C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, clipboard

I would like to allow the user to insert a selected text from any source or application into my Qt application using the middle mouse button.

This functionality is already available with the help of the [QCliboard class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html) on operating systems with X11 Window System. According to the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html), this does not work on Windows because Windows does not support the global mouse selection.

Is there a way to make this functionality available in Windows as well? Can this be achieved with a Qt and C++ implementation? Is there possibly a C++ library that I could integrate which offers this functionality?

Comment: In X11, every selected text is already in "clipboard". (There is actually a concept of primary and secondary selection which I'm not anymore able to repeat.) In Windows, only selecting is not enough - you have to copy explicitly (to get it into clipboard). The only you can do: 1st make your Qt appl. auto-copying into clipboard when text is selected, 2nd paste on middle mouse key overloading the mouse events for the resp. Qt widgets. However, please, keep in mind that the majority of Windows users never saw nor used X11...

Comment: As I'm a fan of [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org), _I can_ select something in an Xterm and paste it into a Windows appl. (The latter, of course, the usual way e.g. [Ctrl+V].) But even this feels strange. (On the other hand, after having worked a certain time in X11, I very miss the middle mouse key in Windows. So, I believe I can understand your motivation.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff
The X11 concept you are describing is explained in the Qt documentation linked in my original post. And your suggestion works from within my application. But if someone selects a text in another application the Qt application will not be informed and because in Windows selections will not be copied to the clipboard you will never have access to the selection. But maybe you're right. In Windows this behaviour is uncommon and should not be implemented. Even if the users are X11 experts which they are in my case. But I would appreciate a solution anyway. Just to now if there is someth.